# Android: Parse inner unstructured Json with Moshi adapters

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, moshi

I have trouble to parse some inner part of JSON (with Moshi) that can vary from a lot and is highly unstructured. Overall it looks like:

```
response: {
    items: [{
        type: "typeA",
        data: {
            "1563050214700-001": {
                foo: 123 ....
            }
        }
    }, {
        type: "typeB",
        data: {
            "1563050214700-002": {[
                // differs a lot from previous one
                {bar: 123 .... }
            ]}
        }
    }]
}
```

And data class structure looks like:

```
data class Response(
    val items: Map<String,List<Item?>>?
) {
    data class Item(
        val type: String?,
        val data: Map<String,List<DataItem?>>?
    ) {
        data class DataItem(
            // members highly unstructured
        )
    }
}
```

Schema of "DataItem" varies a lot. Looks like Moshi codegen supports adapters that can potentially allow manual parsing of these inner data classes but I'm not able to find the right tutorial or example. Ideally, I want entire Response parsed just as if it were a well-defined JSON.

Here is how I use retrofit/moshi

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@MyApp
fun provideMyAppRetrofit(context: Context, @MyApp okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl(context.getString(R.string.APP_BASE_URL))
        .build()
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideMyAppApiService(@MyApp retrofit: Retrofit): MyAppApiService {
    return retrofit.create(MyAppApiService::class.java)
}
```

How do I achieve this? Any sample or reference implementation will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to the polymorphic JSON parsing problems word!

We were writing own JSON adapters that are looking like:

```
internal class CardJsonAdapter(
        moshi: Moshi
) : JsonAdapter<Card>() {

    private val cardTypeAdapter = moshi.adapter(Card.Type::class.java)
    private val amountsWithActionAdapter = moshi.adapter(AmountsWithActionCard::class.java)
    private val backgroundImageCardAdapter = moshi.adapter(BackgroundImageCard::class.java)

    @Suppress("TooGenericExceptionCaught")
    override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): Card = try {

        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        val jsonMap = reader.readJsonValue() as Map<String, Any?>
        val type = cardTypeAdapter.fromJsonValue(jsonMap["type"])
        createCardWithType(type, jsonMap)

    } catch (error: Exception) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.w("CardJsonAdapter", "Failed to parse card", error)
        }
        // Try not to break the app if we get unexpected data: ignore errors and return a placeholder card instead.
        UnknownCard
    }

    override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: Card?) {
        throw NotImplementedError("This adapter cannot write cards to JSON")
    }

    private fun createCardWithType(type: Type?, jsonMap: Map<String, Any?>) = when (type) {
        null -> UnknownCard
        Type.AMOUNTS_WITH_ACTION -> amountsWithActionAdapter.fromJsonValue(jsonMap)!!
        Type.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_WITH_TITLE_AND_MESSAGE -> backgroundImageCardAdapter.fromJsonValue(jsonMap)!!
    }
}
```

However, it is not anymore required. Moshi supports polymorphic JSON parsing now - https://proandroiddev.com/moshi-polymorphic-adapter-is-d25deebbd7c5

Comment: Thanks. However, in the example in the article, different types of payload has a field differentiating "action": "talk", "action": "stream", etc. Can this approach work when there are no such differentiators and purely match different payload schema?

Comment: I don't think so. You have to implement iterating over all possible parsing solutions and choose the correct by yourself. Do you have an influence on BE? Can you ask them to add some differentiation to JSON?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot make BE change. In any case, your response is helpful (on polymorphic parsing) so will mark as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom adapter

```
class YourAdapter {

@FromJson
fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader, itemsAdapter: JsonAdapter<ItemsResponse>): List<ItemsResponse>? {
    val list = ArrayList<ItemsResponse>()
    if (reader.hasNext()) {
        val token = reader.peek()
        if (token == JsonReader.Token.BEGIN_ARRAY) {
            reader.beginArray()
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                val itemResponse = itemsAdapter.fromJsonValue(reader.readJsonValue())
                itemsResponse?.let {
                    list.add(itemResponse)
                }
            }
            reader.endArray()
        }
    }
    return list
}
}
```